# Django JsonResponse converts numbers to string

Tags: django, serialization, axios, jsonresponse

I'm using `JsonResponse(status=200, data=<python_dict_with_data>)` to return from my Django backend API. However, upon inspecting the result of this, all number values get converted to strings (these values are the value portion of the dict, not key). This creates a problem in the frontend receiving this response because now I have to parse them as integers to do formatting and lightweight calculations. Is there a way to prevent this conversion when returned from Django?

Or is there a way the response is parsed correctly in the frontend? I'm using Axios library in React in the frontend.

Comment: JSON objects do not have numbers as keys, only as values. If you run `{1: 1}` it will error, but `{"1": 1}` will succeed in a JSON validator https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent this conversion when returned from Django?

The keys will indeed be transformed into strings, because **ints as keys are *illegal* in JSON**. Indeed, if you use a validator like [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/), you will see that `{1: 1}` is invalid JSON, whereas `{ "1": 1 }` is valid JSON. The Python JSON encoder will thus fallback on converting the integers to strings, to still produce valid content.

If you have to do lightweight calculations, likely using these as *keys* is not a good idea. For example if you have data that looks like:

```
{ 1: 4, 2: 5 }
```

you might consider restructuring the data, for example to:

```
{ "data": [ {"key": 1, "value": 4}, {"key": 2, "value": 5} ] }
```

You can also return it as HTTP response, and do parsing at the JavaScript end, but likely that will only result in more trouble.

---

For `Decimal` numbers, it will also use a string. Django uses by default the [**DjangoJSONEncoder** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/serialization/#djangojsonencoder) which:

> **`Decimal`**, `Promise` (`django.utils.functional.lazy()` objects), `UUID`:
> A **string representation** of the object.

If we for example encode a `Decimal`, we see:

```
>>> djenc = DjangoJSONEncoder()
>>> djenc.encode({'a': Decimal('0.25')})
'{"a": "0.25"}'
```

You can subclass the encoder, and resolve the `Decimal` for example to a `float`, but note that this can result in *loss of precision*. This is exactly why a string is used: to ensure that no digits are lossed:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from decimal import Decimal

class MyDjangoJSONEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, Decimal):
            return float(o)
        return super().default(o)
```

this then produces:

```
>>> mydjenc = MyDjangoJSONEncoder()
>>> mydjenc.encode({'a': Decimal('0.25')})
'{"a": 0.25}'
```

You can then use this encoder in your `JsonResponse`:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def myview(request):
    # …
    JsonResponse(encoder=MyDjangoJSONEncoder, data={'a': Decimal('0.25')})
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified. Keys are all strings in my response, it's the int values that get converted to strings.

Comment: @user1056585: normally that is impossible. Are you sure the values are ints in the `python_dict_with_data`, and not strings themsleves (since `request.GET`/`request.POST` are always string values)?

Comment: Okay, I'll look deeper then. Maybe it's happening because I'm returning numbers as "Decimal" objects?

Comment: @user1056585: ah yes, you can make another encoder (see edited answer) to use a float. But then of course the precision of the decimal will be less, since a `double` represents numbers like the IEEE 754 standard.